# Is it possible to change the UI of alertbox in Phonegap.?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I need to customize the look and feel of an alertbox in phonegap iOS7. I need to redesign the alertbox like having an image in the place of title or some color something like that. ?
How can i achieve it ?

Am using Phonegap 3.3.0,iOS7.
Any Special frameworks available to customize it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a modal with HTML/CSS/JS instead of using the native alert. This would be the same as if you were making a website that needed a custom 'popup'.

something like:

```
<div id="modal-backdrop"></div>
<div id="modal">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button id="btn1">OK</button>
    </div>
</div>

function showModal(title,content) {
   //display backdrop and modal
}

function hideModal() {
    //hide backdrop and modal
}

#modal-backdrop {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}

#modal {
    width: 90%;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks Dawson.I am looking similar to which you have commented and your's look clean :)

Answer (score 0):

So the notification API in phonegap just alls the native alert methods in iOS.

If you want to go beyond the functionality exposed in the stock API then you will need to write a custom phonegap plugin. This will involve a small Obj-C library for the native side and a few lines of javascript HTML side.

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes Tristan.But seems like if I want to use the same in Android,windows.I need to create a individual library and also Its typical how it will perform when calling a native plugin from JS will result miscalculation at times.

Comment: For sure, and there are some great frameworks that have some out of the box JS / HTML functions for this e.g. Sencha Touch & jQuery Mobile.  I just interpreted your question as implementing native behaviour :)

Comment: Ya but I don go wid Jqm as it  mainly supports mobile sites nt mobile apps n also it don give native look n feel. My suggestion

Comment: Yep - I agree with your comments about jQuery Mobile.  Other options are Sencha Touch and Kendo UI.

Comment: Ya that gives better feel. But also I prefer Ionic chocolate chip rather sencha.